# How to successfully get out of this do-while loop?

Tags: c++

This code was smooth sailing until I SPECIFICALLY include the IF-STATEMENT containing a BREAK inside the DO-WHILE LOOP which SHOULD report a math error if fv1 = 0 (for anything divided by zero is undefined). However, unexpected results were printed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const double R = 0.082054;
double f(double a,double b,double P,double T,double v);
double f(double a,double b,double P,double T,double v)
{
    double q =P*pow(v,3)-(P*b+R*T)*pow(v,2)+a*v-a*b;
    return q;
}
double fPrime(double a,double b,double P,double T,double v);
double fPrime(double a,double b,double P,double T,double v)
{
    double s =3*P*pow(v,2)-2*(P*b+R*T)*pow(v,1)+a;
    return s;
}
int main()
{
//INPUT STAGE!
cout << "Use gas constant, R: " << R << endl;

double a,b,P,T,Tc;
cout << "\nUse test value, a: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "\nUse test value, b: ";
cin >> b;
cout << "\nUse pressure, P (atm): ";
cin >> P;
cout << "\nUse absolute temperature, T (K): ";
cin >> T;

double v,v1=0,fv,fv1,N,e;
int iteration = 0;
cout << "\nUse initial guess for molal volume, v: ";
cin >> v;
cout << "\nUse maximum number of iterations, N: ";
cin >> N;
cout << "\nUse tolerance, e: ";
cin >> e;
cout << "\n";

do
{
    v = v1;
    fv = f(a,b,P,T,v);
    fv1 = fPrime(a,b,P,T,v);
    if (fv1=0)
    {
       cout << "Math Error";
       break;
    }
    v1 = v-(fv/fv1);
    cout << iteration+1 << setw(12) << v << setw(16) << v1 << setw(16) << abs(v1-v) << endl;
    iteration++;
}
while(iteration<N && abs(v1-v)>e);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The break statement ends execution of the nearest enclosing loop or conditional statement in which it appears -

And by the way you're assigning 0 to fv1.

use

```
if (fv1 == 0)
```

or

```
if (0 == fv1)
```

Comment: so the break won't terminate the DO-WHILE loop?

Comment: @Mark-Louie in `if (fv1=0)` you're assigning zero to `fv1` and then testing to see if it's true or false.It will always be false because you're **assigning** 0 to `fv1`

Comment: @Mark - Yes, it will - the "conditional statement" is a misnomer of sorts... if (bool) { break; } will exit you from the loop CONTAINING the conditional, not JUST the conditional.

Comment: @peedurrr - Thank you sir for your answers!

Comment: @John - So it's the loop that has the conditional. Thanks sir!

Comment: @Mark-Louie you're welcome.  Note that if you use the `if (0 == fv1)` format, and make the easy mistake of using a `=` instead of an `==` in future code that you'll get a syntax error at compile time that will catch the mistake - as you cannot assign to a constant.  It's a defensive construct that you may see in code (sadly rarely though)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing if condition from `fv1=0` to `fv1==0`
This is assignment operator`=` 
whereas this is comparing operator `==`

Comment: Good answer. You might expand your answer to clarify why the "if (fv1=0)" check is failing. Future people who find your answer may not know why C++ would treat the result of "fv1=0" the same as false.

Comment: Ok now it worked. Thanks sir.  A comparison operator should be used. Now I don't know if the break statement would GET ME OUT of the DO-WHILE LOOP, does it?

Comment: Thanks a lot @a-levy I am a newbie here. I'll have to edit my answer to explain that , right ?